# Отследить нажатие на кнопку блока "Поделиться" Яндекса

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie, ya-share2

Поскажите как реализовать фичу, чтобы отслеживалось нажатие на какую-нибудь кнопку блока "Поделиться", и если она нажата поставить куку.

Comment: а пример кнопки, что вы используете можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При программной инициализации блока можно определить [хук](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/#hooks) `onshare`, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку:

```
Ya.share2('my-share', {
    hooks: {
        onshare: function (name) {
            alert('нажата кнопка' + name);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, это вполне себе реально. При просмотре кода элемента можно заметить, что каждая кнопка имеет свой уникальный класс. К нему и подступаемся. Примерно так:

```
$(".ya-share2").on( "click", ".ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte", function() {
   // нажали на "поделиться в ВК". Делаем, что хотим
});
```

Однако, если у Вас задача, что-то менять на странице, в случаи если пользователь "поделился", то метод этот не надёжный, так как никто не помешает пользователю закрыть окно после нажатия на кнопку, а куку Вы уже запишете.

Comment: у меня попап всплывает, я хочу отслеживать тех кто поделился и больше им не показывать